# How to set dropdown's firsl Item -Select- and remaining Items from a column of table?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, c#-2.0

I m using a dropdown to display "Location" field of a table. I want to set first item of dropdowm as "-Select Location-". I can't set tables first record as "Select" because table is stroed in xml format. And table file is generated dynamicaly.
I am currentaly using as

```
    ddlLocationName.Dispose();
    ddlLocationName.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlLocationName.Items.Add("Select Location");        
    ddlLocationName.DataSource = _section.GetLocations();
    ddlLocationName.DataBind();
    ddlLocationName.AppendDataBoundItems = false;
```

but data is binded repeatedly.
What will be the solution for this problem?
Thaks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have databound, then call ddlLocationName.Items.Insert(0, "Select Location");

Example:

```
ddlLocationName.Items.Clear();
ddlLocationName.DataSource = _section.GetLocations();
ddlLocationName.DataBind();
ddlLocationName.Items.Insert(0, "Select Location"); // Adds the item in the first position
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the items in the form of ListItems:

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Select Location","-1");
ddlLocationName.Items.Add(li);
```

After you have bound your other data, use:

```
ddlLocationName.SelectedValue = "-1";
```

Also, you can add the values of your table in similar way to the ListItem first.